# How to display GWT widgets on RootPanel?

Tags: java, html, gwt, gwt-widgets

I have a `<div>` in `My.html` file:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="
 path/biz.path.nocache.js"></script></head>
 <div id = "div_test"> </div>
```

Now i wrote a `java` class which fetch the `test division` using `Dom`.

```
private void AddWidget() throws Exception{
 _obj = new testWidget(this._session);
 _obj.setSize("100%", "100%");
 _obj.AddTestWidget();
 RootPanel rootpanel = getViewRootPanel(div_test); // returns the division id 
 rootpanel.clear();
 rootpanel.add(_obj);   
}
```

and following is `TestWidget.java`:

```
public class TestWidget extends ContentContainer{
  HorizontalPanel _base = new HorizontalPanel();
  protected FlexTable _bill = new FlexTable();
  Label lblTitle;

  public TestWidget(Session s) {
    super(s);
    _base.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
    _base.setWidth("100%");
    initWidget(_base);
    this._session= s;
    _inheritwidget = new InheritWidget(session);
  }
  public Widget AddTestWidget() {
    System.out.println("In widget");
    lblTitle= new Label("Details");
    lblTitle.setStyleName(Resources.INSTANCE.cssElements().labelBig());
    lblTitle.getElement().getStyle().setPadding(3, Unit.PX);
    _inheritwidget .setWidget(1, 0, lblBillingTitle);
    _inheritwidget .setWidget(2, 0, billingWidget);
    _base.add(_billing);
return _base;
}
}
```

where `InheritWidget` class is extended from `ContentContainer`.
I also check the console and it shows me `In Widget`. It means the flow of code is right. 
Please tell me what should i do to load the content of `AddTestWidget` in `HTML div`.

Is there any part which i am missing?

Comment: What does getViewRootPanel() do? What is the hierarchy of ContentContainer? Cross check you code snippets for other spell checks which might be misleading. It would be easy if we could copy paste you code snippets to run instead of second guessing your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is `ContentContainer`? I am unable to find it in the GWT library. Your `TestWidget` does not extend the GWT Widget class. Because of this, you can't use it as a widget. If you MUST extend `ContentContainer` for your coding needs, you can implement the GWT `isWidget` interface to let GWT know that it is a widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
RootPanel.get().add(Your widget)
```